# Flutter - Button color is not changing on the Tap

Tags: flutter

I have generated answer buttons and when I click the answer button color is not changing. Can you help me to sort this out. Here all I want is to change the color when ever I click a button. Please help me out since I'm very new to flutter. Thank you very much.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'show_question_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class ShowQuestions extends StatefulWidget {
  final String subid;
  const ShowQuestions({super.key, required this.subid});

  @override
  State<ShowQuestions> createState() => _ShowQuestionsState(subid);
}

class _ShowQuestionsState extends State<ShowQuestions> {
  String subid;
  _ShowQuestionsState(this.subid);
  List<Question> questionList = [];
  int currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  int score = 0;
  late final Future myFuture;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFuture = getQuestionData(subid);
  }

  Future getQuestionData(String subid) async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.http("www.ananmanan.lk", "app/getQuestionList.php", {'id': subid}));
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<Question> questions = [];
    for (var u in jsonData) {
      Question question = Question(
        u['ques'],
        u['ans1'],
        u['ans2'],
        u['ans3'],
        u['ans4'],
        u['correct_ans'].toString(),
      );
      questions.add(question);
    }
    return questions;
  }
  //Answer? selectedAnswer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Question Paper'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
        future: myFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Loading...'),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            questionList = snapshot.data;
            return Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 32),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  _questionWidget(),
                  _answerList(),
                  _nextButton(),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      )),
    );
  }

  _questionWidget() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Question ${currentQuestionIndex + 1}/5}',
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20.0,
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
          child: Text(
            questionList[currentQuestionIndex].ques,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _answerList() {
    bool isCorrectAns = false;
    bool isAns1 = false;
    bool isAns2 = false;
    bool isAns3 = false;
    bool isAns4 = false;

    //bool isSelected = answer == selectedAnswer;
    // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
    // if (questionList[currentQuestionIndex].correctanswer == 1) {
    //   isCorrectAns = true;
    // } else {
    //   isCorrectAns = false;
    // }
    if (questionList[currentQuestionIndex].correct_ans == '1') {
      isAns1 = true;
    } else if (questionList[currentQuestionIndex].correct_ans == '2') {
      isAns2 = true;
    } else if (questionList[currentQuestionIndex].correct_ans == '3') {
      isAns3 = true;
    } else if (questionList[currentQuestionIndex].correct_ans == '4') {
      isAns4 = true;
    }
    return Container(
      // width: double.infinity,
      // margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
      // height: 48,
      child: Column(children: [
        _answerButton(questionList[currentQuestionIndex].ans1, isAns1),
        _answerButton(questionList[currentQuestionIndex].ans2, isAns2),
        _answerButton(questionList[currentQuestionIndex].ans3, isAns3),
        _answerButton(questionList[currentQuestionIndex].ans4, isAns4),
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget _answerButton(String ansText, bool correctans) {
    //bool isSelected = answer == selectedAnswer;
    bool click = false;

    if (ansText != '') {
      return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
        height: 48,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(ansText),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: const StadiumBorder(),
            primary: click == true ? Colors.orangeAccent : Colors.white,
            onPrimary: click == true ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            if (correctans) {
              score++;
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return SizedBox.shrink();
    }
  }

  _nextButton() {
    bool isLastQuestion = false;
    if (currentQuestionIndex == questionList.length - 1) {
      isLastQuestion = true;
    }
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
      height: 48,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(isLastQuestion ? 'Submit' : 'Next'),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: const StadiumBorder(),
          primary: Colors.blueAccent,
          onPrimary: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          if (isLastQuestion) {
            showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => _showScoreDialog());
          } else {
            setState(() {
              //selectedAnswer = null;
              currentQuestionIndex++;
            });
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _showScoreDialog() {
    bool isPassed = false;

    if (score >= questionList.length * 0.6) {
      isPassed = true;
    }
    String title = isPassed ? 'Passed' : 'Failed';

    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        title + ' | Score is $score',
        style: TextStyle(color: isPassed ? Colors.green : Colors.redAccent),
      ),
      content: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Restart'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          setState(() {
            currentQuestionIndex = 0;
            score = 0;
            //selectedAnswer = null;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Change the button color of the above code

Comment: Can you remove the code which is not needed. Because it's hard to find the which part of code is exactly bugging.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the state of the variable `click` anywhere. Make sure you do for each "AnswerButton".

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the state again when the button is clicked. Something like this:

```
 child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(ansText),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: const StadiumBorder(),
            primary: click == true ? Colors.orangeAccent : Colors.white,
            onPrimary: click == true ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            if (correctans) {
              score++;
            setState((){
              click = !click;
             )};
```

Comment: tried this. Still not working

Comment: Damn. Somwhere in the code the state will have to set again for the widget to rebuild with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Same as Robert Sandberg mentioned before. Each AnswerButton needs to save it's click state for their own. Therefore make a new StatefulWidget AnswerButton.

Here is a quick implementation for this. Insert the new AnswerButton widget for every answer option.

```
class AnswerButton extends StatefulWidget {
final String text;
final VoidCallback onTap;

  AnswerButton({required this.text, required this.onTap});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _AnswerButtonState();
  }
}

class _AnswerButtonState extends State<AnswerButton> {
  bool click = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
      height: 48,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(widget.text),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: const StadiumBorder(),
          primary: click == true ? Colors.orangeAccent : Colors.white,
          onPrimary: click == true ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
             click = !click;
          });        
          widget.onTap.call();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Furthermore you should follow the advices and replace depricated members like 'primary' and 'onPrimary' of ElevatedButton.

Answer (score 0):

1. `primary` and `onPrimary` are **deprecated** after `v3.1.0`
   Use analogues for them:

- primary -> foregroundColor
- onPrimary -> disabledForegroundColor

2. Use `setState` function when you are changing the **state** variables(`click`)

The new version of your widget:

```
class AnswerButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  const AnswerButton({Key? key, required this.text, required this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _AnswerButtonState();
  }
}

class _AnswerButtonState extends State<AnswerButton> {
  bool click = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
      height: 48,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(widget.text),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: const StadiumBorder(),
          foregroundColor: click == true ? Colors.orangeAccent : Colors.white,
          disabledForegroundColor: click == true ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            click = !click;
            widget.onTap.call();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```